# Eclipse builds but wont launch elf

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, stm32

I am using Eclipse to build but it fails to launch the ELF file.

> Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run

I am using an STM32 ARM board with a blinky prog. GDB with openocd through telnet connection.

Comment: If you think you have a solution to a common problem that haven't been asked before (you have searched for it?), then post it as an *actual* and *proper* question (see [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)) and post an *actual answer* to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 10 installation did not have telnet installed. Once I installed it, the problem was fixed.